# How is the significance level calculated in corrplot in R?

Tags: r, correlation, significance

I am investigating the correlation factors for 13 categorical variables.

To be able to build a correlation matrix, I attributed 1 or 0 to each variable depending on its level. I then constructed a matrix and calculated the correlation factor.
I have used the package corrplot. I have calculated the significance level using the following code.

```
cor.mtest <- function(mat, ...) {
  mat <- as.matrix(mat)
  n <- ncol(mat)
  p.mat<- matrix(NA, n, n)
  diag(p.mat) <- 0
  for (i in 1:(n - 1)) {
    for (j in (i + 1):n) {
      tmp <- cor.test(mat[, i], mat[, j], ...)
      p.mat[i, j] <- p.mat[j, i] <- tmp$p.value
    }
  }
  colnames(p.mat) <- rownames(p.mat) <- colnames(mat)
  p.mat
}
p.mat <- cor.mtest(matrice)
```

I am not sure I understand exactly how the significance level is calculated for each of the correlation. I expected the highest correlation factors to be the most significant ones but it is not the case. For example, the correlation between B and C is among the 5 highest correlation factors, but it is not labelled as statistically significant (p-value 0.05).

The statistically significant correlations obtained with the code mentioned above are: C-A, D-N, D-J, E-N, E-J, I-D, M-N, H-I, J-A, E-D, I-A, I-J and K-D.

Can someone help me to understand why?

Here is my matrice:

```
           A          B           C           D          E          F          G          H          I           J          K          L          M          N
A          NA         -0.204124145-0.327253796-0.17393886-0.11047384 0.17770466 0.07747516-0.04936241 0.042170673 0.27964508-0.03084243 0.45412438 0.27273783 0.26841809
B          -0.20412415NA          -0.240481445-0.03873286-0.08118136-0.03627381 0.05693239-0.03627381 0.009390603-0.05708231 0.08426531 0.09004924 0.26674678 0.07927153
C           -0.3272538-0.240481445NA            0.1248002 0.06544512-0.05815453 0.12407634  0.1508383 0.004234248-0.10467018-0.04236275 -0.2065999 0.09535462  0.0679832
D          -0.17393886 -0.03873286 0.124800202NA          0.26119846 0.13874261 0.08866557-0.06322448-0.171860016-0.28065388 0.26335782 -0.2854407-0.17731715-0.22791043
E          -0.11047384-0.081181365 0.065445119 0.26119846NA         -0.06067985 0.15966387 0.14456083 0.074155081-0.26666679 0.28563978-0.08913118 -0.1248569-0.22093625
F           0.17770466-0.036273813-0.058154526 0.13874261-0.06067985NA           0.2248724-0.00877193-0.023844308-0.04555305 0.19815355-0.05187858 0.06450615 0.07104128
G           0.07747516 0.056932385  0.12407634 0.08866557 0.15966387  0.2248724NA           0.2248724 0.303847721-0.14028442 0.12021134 0.05830386 0.12951876-0.04026408
H          -0.04936241-0.036273813 0.150838301-0.06322448 0.14456083-0.00877193  0.2248724NA          0.367883604-0.04555305-0.04426835 0.16908576-0.13598594-0.12347651
I           0.04217067 0.009390603 0.004234248-0.17186002 0.07415508-0.02384431 0.30384772  0.3678836NA          -0.03135818-0.02619483 0.11639665  0.0196331-0.03349833
J           0.27964508-0.057082312-0.104670181-0.28065388-0.26666679-0.04555305-0.14028442-0.04555305-0.031358183NA          -0.1154414 0.35648931-0.09094761 0.09342798
K          -0.03084243 0.084265305-0.042362748 0.26335782 0.28563978 0.19815355 0.12021134-0.04426835-0.026194825 -0.1154414NA         -0.04940683-0.01173103-0.15568226
L           0.45412438 0.090049245-0.206599899 -0.2854407-0.08913118-0.05187858 0.05830386 0.16908576  0.11639665 0.35648931-0.04940683NA          0.11800138 0.16450294
M           0.27273783 0.266746783 0.095354617-0.17731715 -0.1248569 0.06450615 0.12951876-0.13598594 0.019633103-0.09094761-0.01173103 0.11800138NA          0.52140784
N           0.26841809 0.079271526 0.067983203-0.22791043-0.22093625 0.07104128-0.04026408-0.12347651-0.033498334 0.09342798-0.15568226 0.16450294 0.52140784NA
```

Comment: What are the results of your code? In what way are they unexpected?

Comment: p-value depends also on other things, in particular n.  With large n, you can have low r2 and also low p-value.  Conversely you can have high r2 but low p, if there are few observations in that category.  You need to share the data to see what is going on.

Comment: I guess the first part of my question was more regarding the method. How is the p-value calculated exactly in the context of correlation matrices?

Comment: In the code you show, the p-values come from the `cor.test` function, which is in  the `stats` package. See `?cor.test` for details. (This is also linked from the `?cor.mtest` help page.) Are there particular parts of the documentation that are unclear?

Comment: The default is a two-sided Pearson statistic. From the *Details* section, *"If method is `"pearson"`, the test statistic is based on Pearson's product moment correlation coefficient `cor(x, y)` and follows a t distribution with `length(x)-2` degrees of freedom if the samples follow independent normal distributions. If there are at least 4 complete pairs of observation, an asymptotic confidence interval is given based on Fisher's Z transform."* If you want more details, I think you should ask at stats.stackexchange, as the question seems to be more about statistics than programming.

Comment: (I will say I was surprised too, but dww's explanation makes sense. We know you have missing values due to the `NA`s on the diagonal. So you probably have pairwise samples of different sizes. A small sample with high correlation may not be as significant as a large sample with slightly less correlation. But unless you share your data, we can't investigate that any deeper.)

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Indeed, my sample sizes are different. It makes sense now.